# Java CDI @Inject throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, cdi

I'm testing the Java 7 CDI features following the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-basic.htm) but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I try to access the `greeting` object. The project if a Jar Maven one.

This is the `Greeting` class

```
package greetings;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
@Default
public class Greeting {
    public void  greet(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + ".");
    }
}
```

This is the test class where I'm injecting the bean

```
package greetings;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Tester {

    @Inject Greeting greeting;

    @Test
    public void greet()
    {
        greeting.greet("Mark");
        assertTrue(greeting!=null);
    }
}
```

I also added the `beans.xml` file in the `src/main/resources/META-INF` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

When I run the test I get a `NullPointerException` at the marked line in the `Tester` class.

What do you think about the problem? I browsed a lot of documentation but it seem this problem is solved by adding the `beans.xml`, which is already in the classpath.

Comment: JUnit doesn't work directly with CDI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CDI in jUnit test. Check this:  http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/

Comment: Thank you @Loc Ha, I tried CDI-Unit and the bean is correctly injected.
This is the first time I work with CDI in Java so I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use Arquillian to unit test CDI

http://arquillian.org/

Answer (score 1):

Injection only works for managed beans (and a few other objects like servlets). Test classes get instantiated by JUnit and not by the CDI container, so injection does not work out of the box.

You need a special JUnit runner that injects dependencies into the instantiated test class - e.g. [Pax Exam in CDI mode](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Getting+Started+with+CDI+Tests).